# How to solve a first order recurrence relation when the coefficient of $U_n$ is one?

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve $U_{n+1}=U_n+2n^2+3n+4, U_1=2$

My problem occurs when trying to find the particular equation, as the variable start to cancel out. This is my working:

Reduced form: $U_{n+1}=U_n$

Auxiliary equation: $r^{n+1}=r^n$, so $r=1$.

$C(n)=A(1^n)=A$

$P(n)=an^2+bn+c$

$a(n+1)^2+b(n+1)+c=an^2+bn+c+2n^2+3n+4$

$an^2+2an+a+bn+b+c=an^2+bn+c+2n^2+3n+4$

Considering coefficients of $n^2$: $a=a+2$ (no solutions)

Considering coefficients of $n$: $2a+b=b+3$, so $a=\frac{3}{2}$.

Considering coefficients of constants: $a+b+c=c+4$, so $b=\frac{5}{2}$

Hence, $P(n)=\frac{3}{2}n^2+\frac{5}{2}n$

General solution: $U_n=A+\frac{3}{2}n^2+\frac{5}{2}n$

Since $U_1=2$, $2=A+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{5}{2}$, so $A=-2$

Final solution: $U_n=\frac{3}{2}n^2+\frac{5}{2}n-2$.

However, this final solution does not correspond to the sequence generated by the initial inductive definition. Could any help me by explaining where my method above went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$U_{n+1}-U_n=2n^2+3n+4$$ implies that $U_n=An^3+Bn^2+Cn+D$, then
$$U_{n+1}-U_n=3An^2+(3A+2B)n+(A+B+C)=2n^2+3n+4$$
$$\implies A=2/3, 3A+2B=3,A+B+C=4, \implies B=1/2,C=17/6$$
Next given that $U_1=2=A+B+C+D \implies D=-2$.
Finally we get $$U_n=\frac{2n^2}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{17n}{6}-2$$

Comment: Why does $U_{n+1}-U_n=2n^2+3n+4$ imply that $U_n=An^3+Bn^2+Cn+D$?

Comment: It is just like this: $ dy/dx=Dy=ax^2+bx+c \implies y=ax^3/3+bx^2/2+cx+g$ (at most  a cubic). Similarly, $U_{n+1}-U_n=\Delta U_n=an^2+bn+c$ means  $U_n$ is at most a cubic of $n$. Interestingly if you take $U_n=pn^4+qn^3+ r n^2+sn+t  $ you will get $p=0, q=2/3, r=1/2, s=17/6, t=-2.$ try out!

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand it now.

Comment: Welcome, why not an upvote too!. Also a first order Rec Rel. means you have the first order difference on LHS that is $\Delta=\Delta^{1}=U_{n+1}-U_n$, similarly $\Delta^2=U_{n+2}-2 U_{n+1}+U_n$ if this equals a quadratic, then $U_n$ will be at  most a fourth degree polynomial.